# JIMFS for production in memory filesystem

Tags: java, production, jimfs

I have a specific use case where it would benefit me to abstract a normal filesystem into an in memory one since we often switch between the two for performance reasons. 
Can JIMFS be used in a production environment or is it purely made for testing?

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular reason it can't be used in production. Testing is just the most common use case.